# Вывод по дате из нескольких таблиц YII2

Tags: yii2, вывод

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите как смешать данные именно по дате публикации, а не по разделу? Все выводится, причем по времени, но таким образом: сначала News 10 новостей, потом Directway 10 новостей и тд..., а нужно одной лентой и подряд по дате.

Есть виджет:

```
public function run()
{
    $items = array_merge(
        News::find()
            ->where(['visible' => 1, 'deleted' => 0])
            ->orderBy('time_create DESC')
            ->limit($this->count)
            ->all(),
        Directway::find()
            ->where(['visible' => 1, 'deleted' => 0])
            ->orderBy('time_create DESC')
            ->limit($this->count)
            ->all(),
        Lifestyle::find()
            ->where(['visible' => 1, 'deleted' => 0])
            ->orderBy('time_create DESC')
            ->limit($this->count)
            ->all()
    );

    return $this->render('newsList', [
        'items' => $items,
    ]);
}
```

Есть view

```
 <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
       <?= $item->name ?>
       <?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($item->time_create, 'dd.MM, HH:mm') ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: А мердж по какому значению происходит, ключ отдаваемых массивов - время, или что? Проверьте документацию array_merge. Для достижения результата нужно чтобы ключ был датой, и по нему бы делалась сортировка для вывода.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, попробую.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Daniel Protopopov за наводку! Итак решение для смешивания масивов с определенным ключом и вывод по порядку независимо от расположения таблиц. В моем случае виджет:

```
public function run()
{
    $items = ArrayHelper::merge(
        News::find()
            ->where(['visible' => 1, 'deleted' => 0])
            ->orderBy('time_create DESC')
            ->limit($this->count)
            ->all(),


        Directway::find()
            ->where(['visible' => 1, 'deleted' => 0])
            ->orderBy('time_create DESC')
            ->limit($this->count)
            ->all(),


        Lifestyle::find()
            ->where(['visible' => 1, 'deleted' => 0])
            ->orderBy('time_create DESC')
            ->limit($this->count)
            ->all()
);

    ArrayHelper::multisort($items, ['time_create'], [SORT_DESC]);

    return $this->render('newsList', [
        'items' => $items,
    ]);
}
```

И

Во VIEW

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
   <?= $item->name ?>
   <?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($item->time_create, 'dd.MM, HH:mm') ?><?php endforeach; ?>
```